# PHP/ MySQL query not executing

Tags: php, mysql

As the title says my PHP/ MySQL query not executing

Can some have a look what am doing wrong ?

```
  $name = ((isset($_POST['name']))?sanitize($_POST['name']):'');
  $email = ((isset($_POST['email']))?sanitize($_POST['email']):'');
  $password = ((isset($_POST['password']))?sanitize($_POST['password']):'');
  $confirm = ((isset($_POST['confirm']))?sanitize($_POST['confirm']):'');
  $errors = array();
  if($_POST){
    $emailQuery =$db->query("SELECT  FROM users1 WHERE email = '$email'");
    $emailCount = mysqli_num_row($emailQuery);

        if($emailCount != 0){
          $errors[] = 'That email already exists in our database.';
        }
```

Comment: SELECT  FROM users1 WHERE email = '$email'  you are missing what you are selecting.

Comment: As far as I know, `$_POST` will always exist because it is a superglobal; use `if($_POST['email'])` at the very least.  You don't need to declare your `mysqli_num_rows` if you are only going to use it once: `if(mysqli_num_rows($emailQuery)){$error[]...}`.  And finally, you should be using a prepared statement to protect against injection.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems in your code

1. You are missing * in your query
2. mysqli_num_row Should be mysqli_num_rows

Here is correct code

```
  $name = ((isset($_POST['name']))?sanitize($_POST['name']):'');
  $email = ((isset($_POST['email']))?sanitize($_POST['email']):'');
  $password = ((isset($_POST['password']))?sanitize($_POST['password']):'');
  $confirm = ((isset($_POST['confirm']))?sanitize($_POST['confirm']):'');
  $errors = array();
  if($_POST){
    $emailQuery =$db->query("SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE email = '$email'");
    $emailCount = mysqli_num_rows($emailQuery);

        if($emailCount != 0){
          $errors[] = 'That email already exists in our database.';
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, Worked like charm